# why isn't int converted to double in printf?

Tags: c, int, double, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is conversion of float/double to int handled in printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398791/how-is-conversion-of-float-double-to-int-handled-in-printf)

```
main()
{
    printf("%f",1);
}
```

The output I expected was `1.000000`,i.e the *int 1* being upcasted to *double 1.000000* , but it gave `0.000000`. Why is it so ?

Comment: You're missing the prototype for `printf()`. Even with the prototype, your program would still be in error.

Comment: Why on earth *would* it be converted to double?

Answer (score 4):

When a non-matching argument is provided to the formatting directive (in this case an `int` to a `%f`) the resulting behavior is ***undefined***.

This question, or some variation of it, comes up periodically, see   [What is printf's behaviour when printing an int as float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203754/what-is-printfs-behaviour-when-printing-an-int-as-float?rq=1) and [problem with printf function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232603/problem-with-printf-function?rq=1) for examples/more information.